# Angular.js : Calculating the total of a list of numbers

Tags: angularjs

I need to have a list of numbers display with the total. When someone enters a new number into an input box, the number will be added to the list displayed and the total will change accordingly.

using angular.js...

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 3):

While itamar's answer works without any doubt, you can write this like this (a bit cleaner in my opinion) :

**Controller**

Use `reduce` for total computation :

```
$scope.numbers = [1,2,3];

$scope.updateTotal = function () {
    $scope.total = numbers.reduce(function (total, number) {
        if (number) {        
            total += number;
        }

        return total;
    }, 0);
};
```

**Markup**

```
<span>{{ total }}</span>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="number in numbers">
        <input type="number" ng-model="number" ng-change="updateTotal()">
    </li>      
</ul>
```

Since you know when the total value should get updated, better use `ng-change` here so the computation is only done when needed.

On a side note, you can use `type="number"` in the input so only numbers can be entered.

Comment: Shouldn't that be total += number in your callback?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow - next time please provide some code you wrote yourself. In the meantime - I wrote yours for you :-)

JS in your controller:

```
$scope.numbers = [1,2,3];
    $scope.getTotals = function(){
    var total = 0;
total = $scope.numbers.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev + curr;
});
    return total;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="number in numbers"><input ng-model="number"></li>
<li>{{getTotals()}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the asker should make sure he wraps his html in ng-app and ng-controller directives, etc. in terms of your answer - nice one BUT i would use angular.forEach instead of using a plain JavaScript for loop - cheers

Comment: even better - EcmaScript 5's Array.reduce method was made for this task!

Comment: switched to .reduce() because @danday74 forced me to learn something.